# New to C++ pointers; trying to retrieve a child's object from a vector of a pointer to the parent class. Help would be appreciated

Tags: c++, pointers

So, I'm trying to create an entity management system in which one container has access to many and varying types of objects. I'm having some difficulties, and would appreciate any help that the Stack Overflow community can lend. Cheers in advance.

```
int main() {
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Prop>> x;
    Prop y;
    Actor z; // has actor-only "xyz" property (string);
    x.emplace_back(y); // 0
    x.emplace_back(z); // 1
    std::cout << (Actor)x[1].get()->xyz;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using C++17 and speed is not the main focus at the moment, you could take a look at [std::variant](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant). It is a union that can hold almost any type, as long it fullfils its requirements.

In your example above you are not dealing much with pointers. Watch out for the terminology, although `unique_ptr` contains the word `ptr`, in the classical sense the reader might expect you are talking about **raw-pointers**. `unique_ptr` is a smart pointer that owns and manages the object on its own.

**MVCE:** https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/-zUUbK

```
#include <vector>
#include <variant>

class Foo {};
class Bar {};

using FooBarVector = std::vector<std::variant<Foo, Bar>>;

int main()
{
    FooBarVector objects = {Foo(), Bar()};
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I was remarkably pessimistic about a non-pointer approach, but I'm pleased to say that this solution actually works quite well. In the context of game development, I have no doubts that the mentioned speed issues will eventually come back to bite me in the ass, but for now: excellent, and thank you.